# Resize sensor - Proportional div sizing in CSS

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout with three horizontal columns which I want to fill the full size of the window with no scrollbars.

In the center column sits a div which will show a A4 page. The dimentions need to be always be proportional and if the browser is resized the div needs to resize accordingly on the fly.

The contents of the div will also also need to be scaled. The div will contain a number of elements including text and images which need to be scaled down to match the parent page container.

My first attempt I tried;

```
A4-Portrait {width: auto; height: auto;max-width: 595.296px;max-height: 
841.896px;}
```

But of course this dosent resize proportionaly nor scale down the DIV only resize the height and width to accomadate the containing space.

I have coded a simple sample to illustrate the problem.

```css
body 
{
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, main, footer 
{
  padding: 1em;flex: 1;
}

header, footer
{
  background-color: #999;
}

main 
{
  flex: 2;
  background-color: grey;
}

page 
{
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}

.A4-Portrait 
{
  width: 595.296px;
  height: 841.896px;
}
```

```html
<header>[header]</header>

<main>
  <page id="pageSize" class="A4-Portrait">
      [page]
  </page>
  
</main>

<footer>[footer]</footer>
```

UPDATE: I was not able to find a pure CSS solution so I ended up using 'Fit.js'

Including the JS file I just had to add the following code to implement. The A4 page size in px was intact and the JS worked out the max dimentions back from the parent DIV. This also watched user resizing of the browser.

```
// get element references
var foo = document.querySelector('main');
var bar = document.querySelector('#pageSize');
// fit bar into foo
// the third options argument is optional, see the README for defaults
// https://github.com/soulwire/fit.js
var watching = fit(bar, foo, {

    // Alignment
    hAlign: fit.CENTER, // or fit.LEFT, fit.RIGHT
    vAlign: fit.CENTER, // or fit.TOP, fit.BOTTOM

    // Fit within the area or fill it all (true)
    cover: false,

    // Fit again automatically on window resize
    watch: true,

    // Apply computed transformations (true) or just
    // return the transformation definition (false)
    apply: true
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking to be honest. Are you asking how to implement the `CSS-Element-Queries` plugin you linked, or are you asking for a vanilla CSS solution? If you want the paper to be A4 size, it'll be a fixed size, or do you simply want a div that will scale to a percentage of the viewport height/width respectively?

Comment: The plugin is not important. I simply want to scale the page div (and everything inside) to the max width and height available whilst retaining the .A4-Portrait size proportions.

Comment: If you don't need to use the plugin, Kevin's answer should help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set everything with vw, it will all scale with the width of the screen. I think this is what you were after?

I set the page's dimensions by taking the A4 page ratio, which is 1:1.414. I set the width to what I thought looked good, then used `calc` for the height, taking the width I set, and multiplying it by 1.414.

For the font-sizes, it all becomes a bit of a guess in a way though. This might be of some help in figuring out how to set font-sizes though: http://emilolsson.com/tools/vw-unit-calc-an-online-responsive-css-font-size-calculator/

```css
body 
{
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, main, footer 
{
  padding: 1em;flex: 1;
}

header, footer
{
  background-color: #999;
}

main 
{
  flex: 2;
  background-color: grey;
}

page 
{
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}

.A4-Portrait 
{
  width: 80vw;
  height: calc(1.414 * 80vw);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
.page-header {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
   
.page-body {
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<header>[header]</header>

<main>
  <page id="pageSize" class="A4-Portrait">
      <h1 class="page-header">Page header</h1>
      <p class="page-body">Page text page text page text</p>
  </page>
  
</main>

<footer>[footer]</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great start. However I wish to resize the height as well. If you open the example full page there are still scroll bars, I would like the initial page to resize to the max height and width without increasing page size. Also ideally the page size needs to be be absolute in PX if possible, as I wish to generate a print ready document from the DIV.

Comment: You could set everything using vh instead of vw if you don't want to at all... exact same principle, except the calc() will be used for the width.
You could also use a @media print { } to take care of what it will look like when printed, setting all the values to exactly what you want.

Comment: A quick question in relation to all this... would it not be easier to simply have a .jpg of the document, and have that scale to the page? Would making printing it a lot easier too.....

Comment: The intended use of this is a poster creator so its intended the user will create elements on the A4 page so the content is yet unknown and dynamic. The absolute value is useful for this as well as the user may wish to place elements of PX sizes onto the A4 page.